# Workfront API Auth request (Machine to Machine Application) is returning 404 error

Tags: workfront-api

I'm making an auth POST request to the `https://example.my.workfront.com/integrations/oauth2/api/v1/jwt/exchange` (note: actual request has '`example.my`' subdomain replaced with the real Workfront subdomain for my org) endpoint with the required `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `jwt_token` values but receiving the following 404 response and error message in the Response:

`{"statusCode":404,"error":true,"type":"Not Found","message":"Invalid Host"}`

I searched the API docs and Workfront forum for any additional information on what could cause the error but had no luck. Does anyone know what is causing this error?

For context, this request seems to work fine from Postman on my local machine (i.e. auth token is returned) but fails on the server that is being used for this machine to machine application.

Comment: Looks like a DNS issue if its working on local machine.   404 means its not found, so thats pretty big.  Check your HOSTS file and maybe force that address in there.

Comment: What's really strange is that I can successfully make this API request to get a Session ID:

`https://example.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/login?username=EXAMPLE_USERNAME&password=EXAMPLE_PASSWORD`

That POST request made from the application server returns the expected 200 response with JSON payload that includes the Session ID and other data.

Comment: Hold up I think I spotted it ... Method="POST" is for Form / Internal data ..  whereas Method="GET" is to get from ANOTHER external source usually (another website etc)  Simplified a bit .. but POST is to get data from a form, and GET its from the URL via ?blaablaa=

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, both requests (the one in the question above) and the one in my comment are using POST method. Both are constructed per the API docs, as well. Strangely, the POST to get a session ID, used in my test above, does not include a payload--this is also per API docs. My feeling is that it is networking/DNS but I'm not sure how since other requests are working (including testing some GET). I wish Adobe had more info in their API docs on the error responses and potential causes...would make troubleshooting this a bit easier.

Comment: Ahh okay hmm .. yeah I couldn't find anything to link as well.  Granted an error 404 means it was not reached, so an actual error message beyond that one would be futile.  But I'm willing to bet you are right about it being a DNS thing, I wonder if you can edit your local HOST file and maybe force it to work.

Comment: The Invalid Host part makes me really think ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the request to the Workfront API was including the port in the host Header value, i.e. `example.my.workfront.com:443`.

Excluding the port so the host Header value is in the format `example.my.workfront.com` resolved the issue and provided the expected 200 response with auth token.